# Paypal recurring payment - Android

Tags: android, paypal, paypal-subscriptions, recurring-billing

I need to add Paypal recurring payment option in Android application. Is it possible using Paypal Android MECL or MPL SDK?

I googled and can't find any solution. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: :- have you got the answer? actually i need to add paypal recurring payment option in android application.

Comment: it's posted 3 years ago. Really I don't remember what I did.

Comment: :- yes i know that post 3 year ago , now i want recurring payment with pay pal. below the post you write the solution , the solution is that according the developer@paypal.com, 
down vote
accepted
Reply from Developer@paypal.com

We don’t have a specific recurring payment Android SDK, but you can use Mobile Express Checkout for that functionality. 
still after 3 year age i could not get android sdk for paypal recurring

Comment: Yes.. That's what the reply I got from Paypal Developer before 3 years. Am not sure whether now they have a new SDK for recurring payment or not.

Comment: can you give me propar way for recurring payment in paypal now ?

Comment: @ckpatel Its more than three years I worked on Paypal. I don't have any knowledge on the latest things. So please look for some other source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reply from Developer@paypal.com

We don’t have a specific recurring payment Android SDK, but you can use Mobile Express Checkout for that functionality.  Please refer to [this page](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/products/mobile-overview) for more information.  If you have further questions, please create a ticket with our tech [support team](https://www.paypal.com/dts) for assistance with this issue.